# HTML pagination messed up on first page and after that it works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I am trying to use this simple pagination javascript library for my pagination on HTML tables (http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) (specifically light theme) but somehow my pagination is not working on my html tables..

I want to show 2 items in my table in one page by using above pagination javascript.. And as soon as I click on second pagination tab, it should show me next two items and keep on going until it is finished..

Below is my full HTML code in which I have tried using the same above pagination javascript.. **It is almost working for me** but somehow for the first time, when I load the HTML page, it shows me everything, meaning all the rows in one HTML table but if I click on page number 2, then it starts showing me correctly.. So somesthing I have messed up for sure..

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
<link href="../simplePagination.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <style type="text/css">
table {
    width: 40em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    }

    thead {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    }

    td {
    width: 10em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    }

    tbody {
    background: #ccc;
    }

    </style>

    <script>

function test(pageNumber)
{

  var page="#page-id-"+pageNumber;
  $('.select').hide()
  $(page).show()

}

</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
    <table class="paginated">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>

                <th>B</th>

                <th>C</th>

                <th>D</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr class="select" id="page-id-1">
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="select" id="page-id-2">
                <td>5</td>

                <td>6</td>

                <td>7</td>

                <td>8</td>
            </tr>

            <tr  class="select" id="page-id-3">
                <td>9</td>

                <td>10</td>

                <td>11</td>

                <td>12</td>
            </tr>

            <tr  class="select" id="page-id-4">
                <td>13</td>

                <td>14</td>

                <td>15</td>

                <td>16</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="select" id="page-id-5">
                <td>17</td>

                <td>18</td>

                <td>19</td>

                <td>20</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="select" id="page-id-6">
                <td>21</td>

                <td>22</td>

                <td>23</td>

                <td>24</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="select" id="page-id-7">
                <td>25</td>

                <td>26</td>

                <td>27</td>

                <td>28</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

<div id="choose">
</div>


    <script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#choose').pagination({
            items: 10,
            itemsOnPage: 2,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber){test(pageNumber)}
        });
    });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place 2 or more items per page being rows of the table you need to wrap them around by tbody elements and set those as pages.

Problem with script is that you don't set first page as visible only on init.

I think it should look something like that:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>
<link href="../simplePagination.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <style type="text/css">
table {
    width: 40em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    }

    thead {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    }

    td {
    width: 10em;
    padding: 0.3em;
    }

    tbody {
    background: #ccc;
    }

    </style>

    <script>

function test(pageNumber)
{

  var page="#page-id-"+pageNumber;
  $('.select').hide()
  $(page).show()

}

</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
    <table class="paginated">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>

                <th>B</th>

                <th>C</th>

                <th>D</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="select" id="page-id-1">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>

                <td>2</td>

                <td>3</td>

                <td>4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>5</td>

                <td>6</td>

                <td>7</td>

                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody class="select" id="page-id-2">
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>

                <td>10</td>

                <td>11</td>

                <td>12</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>13</td>

                <td>14</td>

                <td>15</td>

                <td>16</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody   class="select" id="page-id-3">
            <tr>
                <td>17</td>

                <td>18</td>

                <td>19</td>

                <td>20</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>21</td>

                <td>22</td>

                <td>23</td>

                <td>24</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody   class="select" id="page-id-4">
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>

                <td>26</td>

                <td>27</td>

                <td>28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>29</td>

                <td>30</td>

                <td>31</td>

                <td>32</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<div id="choose">
</div>


    <script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#choose').pagination({
            items: 8,
            itemsOnPage: 2,
            currentPage: 1,
            onInit: function () { test(1); },
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            onPageClick: function(pageNumber){test(pageNumber)}
        }).pagination('redraw');
    });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```